# Unable to Bind NIC to Driver VFIO-PCI

Tags: drivers, linux-kernel, pci, bus

### Context

I'm attempting to run the packet generator MoonGen, however, it requires me to bind a NIC to the VFIO-PCI driver. Therefore, I must first unbind a NIC from its current driver, then rebind it with the VFIO-PCI driver.

### Unbinding

I began by unbinding my NIC with PCI address 0000:03:00.1 from the current driver, mlx5_core:

```
$ echo -n "0000:03:00.1" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/mlx5_core/unbind
```

dmesg, running in another window, reports:

```
[Aug30 23:36] mlx5_3:wait_for_async_commands:735:(pid 1605): done with all pending requests  
[  +0.048579] (0000:03:00.1): E-Switch: cleanup
```

This makes me believe that everything went smoothly, and using tools provided by DPDK's devbind module alongside ifconfig, I was assured that my NIC was unbound.

### Binding

Now, I attempt to bind my NIC with the VFIO-PCI driver by prompting:

```
$ echo -n "0000:03:00.1" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/bind
```

Which returned the error message:

```
bash: echo: write error: No such device
```

Looking at the dmesg report, it states:

```
[Aug31 03:37] vfio-pci: probe of 0000:03:00.1 failed with error -22
```

### Question

After researching the error message for some time, I have yet to discover its meaning. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that I had to preemptively install Mellanox OFED for my Mellanox MT27710 ConnectX-4 NIC.

For anyone with the same problem and NIC or other Mellanox NICs (confined to MLX4 and MLX5 since those are the only Mellanox NICs compatibile with DPDK), https://community.mellanox.com/s/article/how-to-install-mellanox-ofed-on-linux--rev-4-4-2-0-7-0-x is a great resource on how to resolve this issue.